# SQL Server 2016 wrong value on xml query

Tags: sql-server, xml

While I'm querying my database, I encountered this problem:

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.

My select is the following:

```
SELECT 
    Tab.value('(/root//' +
    (SELECT name FROM table where id = 'id' and index = '3')
     + '/step)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM 
    table2
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: could you paste the xml text?

Comment: As the error says: you **cannot** combine parts of your string with a query result - the first argument of the `.value()` call **must be** a string literal - nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you: You cannot use variables to build the `XPath`. There are two approaches:

#### `XQuery`predicate on `local-name()`

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES('elementName'),('OneMore');
GO

CREATE TABLE tab2(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeXML XML);
INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES
 (N'<root><a><elementName>Yeah! (inside a)</elementName></a></root>')
,(N'<root><b><elementName>Yeah! (inside b)</elementName></b></root>')
,(N'<root><a><blah>Oh no!</blah></a></root>');
GO


SELECT 
    SomeXml.value('(/root//*[local-name()=sql:column("SomeName")])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM tab2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SomeName FROM tab1 where ID = 1) AS GetTheColumnName
GO

DROP TABLE tab1;
DROP TABLE tab2;
```

#### dynamically created statement

Same scenario as above, but the select looks like this:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)='SELECT SomeXml.value(''(/root//' + (SELECT SomeName FROM tab1 where ID = 1) + ')[1]'', ''nvarchar(max)'') FROM tab2;';
EXEC(@cmd);
```

#### Both approaches are limited:

- `local-name()` you cannot build any XPath, but just filter for existing names
- `dynamically created` cannot be used in inline / *ad-hoc* queries. That's a *no-go* in `VIEW`s or (inline)functions.